# jquery - slideDown each of parent ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, slidedown

I have a multilevel menu. Each of level is a list with ul-tag. Each point of the menu is li-tag.

I want to slide down all of parent uls of the current point of the menu when loading the page.

Now I do the next:

```
var parents = selector.parents('ul');

parents.each(function(index, parent){
    parent.slideDown();
});
```

But I get an error 'Uncaught TypeError: parent.slideDown is not a function'. And when I try to print a parent in console, I get the raw html. How can I get an access to the single parent inside each to make a slideDown? Or slide down all parents in any ways.

Comment: Please include all relevant code(html), maybe `$(parent).slideDown()` will do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parent` is the reference to a DOM element, not a jQuery object. (That is simply how .each works.)

You need to wrap it in `$()` before you can call jQuery methods on it.

```
parents.each(function(index, parent){
    $(parent).slideDown();
});
```

Comment: So simple, but I forgot it) Thanks)